# proof that $f$ is a bijection.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $f: X \to Y $ a function and $A \subseteq X, \ B \subseteq Y$.

Prove that if:
for all $A \subseteq X, \ B \subseteq Y$ : $f^{-1}(B) \subset A \iff  B \subset f(A) $
than $f$ is a bijection

I found the proof for $f$ being a surjection but i can't find the proof for $f$ being an injection.
And I don't really see why it has to be an injection.

Can someone explain this to me and help with the proof?

Comment: It's not true as written... take for exemple $f(x)=x^2$, $A=[-1,1]$, $B=[0,1]$. Then $f^{-1}(B)=A$, $f(A)=B$ but $f$ is not injective. I guess that you rather mean for all $A\subset X$ and all $B\subset Y$, $f^{-1}(B)\subset A\iff B\subset f(A)$.

Comment: Say $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$ and let $A=\{x_1\}$, $B=\{y\}$.